# What is KNOPPIX shell's start-up file?

Tags: bash, shell, knoppix

I'm trying to install virtualenvwrapper and I got to change the settings of my shell's start-up file (like .bashrc, .zhrc, .profile, etc) to write this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The problem is that I don`t know what is it called in KNOPPIX, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Check which shell you're using with this command: <sup>[[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html)]</sup>

```
ps -p $$
```

Then check your shell's documentation or use your favorite search engine to find out how that file is called. For the most widely used `bash` shell it's [`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/1937994).